# Copying Arrays and cleaning up

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to copy my array into a larger array and then delete the old array to clean things up. The class has an `int` and a pointer, and overrides the destructor to make sure it doesn't delete the pointer when I can `delete []`. but I get a exception thrown on my `delete []`. I use `= new field[1000];` to initialize the array.

I get `"Collections.exe has triggered a breakpoint."`, but the breakpoint isn't mine.

```
inline void _resize(unsigned int newTableSize, bool _trimCalled){ 
            if (newTableSize < tableSize && _trimCalled == false) {
                _trim();
                return; 
            }
            field* newTable = new field[newTableSize]; 
            for (unsigned int x = 0; x < newTableSize; x++)
                newTable[x] = table[x];
            tableSize = newTableSize;  
            delete[] table;
            table = newTable;   

    }
inline void _trim(){
    // compact the table 
    // fill in from the end of the table
    for (int x = tableSize; !emptyPlaces.empty() ; x--){
        if (table[x].used = true){
            table[emptyPlaces.top()] = table[x];
            emptyPlaces.pop();
        }
    }
    // trim the excess
    _resize((unsigned int)(usedFields * 1.1 + 10), true);


template<typename key, typename object> class DictonaryArray {
    struct field{
        field(){ this->key = 0; this->_object = nullptr; this->used = false; }
        field(key _key, object __object){;
            key = _key;
            _object = new object();
            *_object = __object;
            this->used = true;
        }
        ~field(){ 
        }
        key key;
        object* _object;
        bool used;
    };
```

Comment: In C++ we spell it this way: `std::vector<int> table(1000); ... table.resize(newTableSize);`.

Comment: Sorry old paste it is table in the code.
I wanted to write my own implementation.

Comment: Is this for an academic assignment or personal growth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table = newtable;; 
delete[] table;
```

Looks suspicious.

Maybe you want,

```
delete[] table;
table = newTable;
```

Delete old table and assign address of new Table to it.

**Edit 1:**

Also , 
Assuming `tableSize` is the size of the old table

```
for (unsigned int x = 0; x < newTableSize; x++)
```

needs to be

```
for (unsigned int x = 0; x < tableSize; x++)
```

because `table[x]` can only be read upto `tableSize-1`

Comment: Sorry to say, but I've already done that. when I corrected the delete name, I moved it out of order my accident.

Comment: @joshuaWaring Check Edit. Also, can you just add the definition of `field`

Comment: Three years late, but that looks like the problem I made. Up vote for you.